# Netsh failing to set DHCP in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dhcp, netsh

I'm trying to configure a network adapter to DHCP, but I can't seem to get any results. Here is my code:

```
private void btnResetDHCP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NIC nic = (NIC)comboNetworkList.SelectedItem;
    string cmd = String.Format("netsh interface ip set address name=\"{0}\" source=dhcp", nic.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(cmd);
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", cmd);
    psi.Verb = "runas";
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.StartInfo = psi;

    p.Start();
}
```

I've literally copy and pasted the resulting command that gets printed to the console into a command prompt window and was able to successfully changed the adapter to DHCP. However, the above code fails to do anything to the chosen network adapter. Why would the command work in command prompt but not via the Process class?

Comment: Are you running your program "as Administrator?"